# Get request in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to send a get request to API usign Socket.IO

```
//socket
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var apiPath='localhost:1242/api/v1/';

app.listen(8090);


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('getBanners', function(data){
    socket.get(apiPath+'1/1/1', function (resData) {
      console.log(resData)
      socket.emit('response', {data:resData})
    })
  });
});
```

My view

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = io('http://localhost:8090');
            socket.on('response',function(data){
                alert(data)
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The idea is keep refreshing the data in case the api info is changed.
But I don't know how make a GET request on SocketIo side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution
In my socket I used *request* module

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var apiPath='http://localhost:1242/api/v1/';
var request = require('request');

app.listen(8090);


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('getBanners', function(data){
    request.get(apiPath+'1/1/1',function (error, response, body){
      socket.emit('result', {res:JSON.parse(body)})
    })
  });
});
```